# PHP SeekableIterator : catch OutOfBoundsException or check valid() method?

Tags: php, exception, spl, seekableiterator

So I'm not sure if this is buggy design with PHP, or if there is an understood logic to handling inconsistent outcomes for the same interface.

The SeekableIterator interface has two methods (`seek` and `valid`) that are either in conflict with one another or should be working consistently with each other, but I'm seeing both.

The documentation for the interface says that `seek` should throw an exception of class OutOfBoundsException, but this seems to negate the usefulness of `valid` unless the iterator position is updated (making `valid` return false) before throwing the exception (which apparently must be caught).

### Three test examples

#### Example 1.

#### Custom class implementing SeekableIterator, as provided by example in docs:

The class:

```
class MySeekableIterator implements SeekableIterator {

    private $position;

    private $array = array(
        "first element",
        "second element",
        "third element",
        "fourth element"
    );

    /* Method required for SeekableIterator interface */

    public function seek($position) {
        if (!isset($this->array[$position])) {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException("invalid seek position ($position)");
        }

        $this->position = $position;
    }

    /* Methods required for Iterator interface */

    public function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    public function valid() {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}
```

#### Example 1. Test :

```
echo PHP_EOL . "Custom Seekable Iterator seek Test" . PHP_EOL;

$it = new MySeekableIterator;

$it->seek(1);
try {
    $it->seek(10);
    echo $it->key() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $it->valid() . PHP_EOL;
} catch (OutOfBoundsException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $it->key() . PHP_EOL; // outputs previous position (1)
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $it->valid() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Test 1 Output:

```
Custom Seekable Iterator seek Test
invalid seek position (10)
1
Is valid? 1
```

#### Example 2:

#### Using native ArrayIterator::seek

Test 2 Code:

```
echo PHP_EOL . "Array Object Iterator seek Test" . PHP_EOL;

$array = array('1' => 'one',
               '2' => 'two',
               '3' => 'three');

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

$iterator->seek(1);
try {
    $iterator->seek(5);
    echo $iterator->key() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $iterator->valid() . PHP_EOL;
} catch (OutOfBoundsException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $iterator->key() . PHP_EOL;  // outputs previous position (1)
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $iterator->valid() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Test 2 Output:

```
Array Object Iterator seek Test
Seek position 5 is out of range
1
Is valid? 1
```

#### Example 3:

#### Using native DirectoryIterator::seek

Test 3 Code:

```
echo PHP_EOL . "Directory Iterator seek Test" . PHP_EOL;

$dir_iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$dir_iterator->seek(1);
try {
    $dir_iterator->seek(500);  // arbitrarily high seek position
    echo $dir_iterator->key() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $dir_iterator->valid() . PHP_EOL;
} catch (OutOfBoundsException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $dir_iterator->key() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Is valid? " . (int) $dir_iterator->valid() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Test 3 Output:

```
Directory Iterator seek Test
90
Is valid? 0
```

So how would one reasonably expect to know whether to use `valid()` to confirm valid position after `seek($position)` while also anticipating that the `seek()` might throw an Exception instead of updating the position, so that `valid()` returns true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `directoryIterator::seek()` method here is not implemented with an exception. Instead it will just return no value, and let `valid()` handle it.

Your other example, the `ArrayObject::seek()` does work "correctly" and throws an `OutOfBoundsException`.

The reasoning is simple: the `ArrayObject` (and most likely, most custom implementations too) will know beforehand how many elements it contains, and thus can quickly check its bounds. The `DirectoryIterator` however, must read the directory entities from disk one by one in order to reach the given position. It does so by literally calling `valid()` and `next()` in a loop. This is the reason why the `key()` has changed, and `valid()` returns `0`.

The other iterators will not even touch the current iterator state, and can quickly decide if your request falls in its range or not.

On a sidenote: if you want to seek a position in the DirectoryIterator backwards, it will reset the iterator first, and then starts iterating each element again. So if you are on position 1000, and do a `$it->seek(999)`, it will actually iterate 999 elements again.

IMHO, The `DirectoryIterator` is not a good implementation of the `seekableIterator` interface. It's intended to quickly jump to a certain element within the iterator and clearly, with a directoryIterator this is not something that is doable. Instead, a full iteration must be done, which results in a changed iterator state.

The `seekableIterator` interface is useful for filterIterators that do something with the range of the iterator. Within the SPL, this is only the `LimitIterator`. When you do:

```
$it = new ArrayIterator(range('a','z'));
$it = new LimitIterator($it, 5, 10));
```

When the limitIterator detects that the given iterator has implemented the `seekableIterator` interface, it will call `seek()` to quickly jump to the 5th element, otherwise it will just iterate until it reached the 5th element.

Conclusion: do not use the `seekableIterator` when you cannot quickly jump to a position or check bounds. At best you gain nothing, at worst you get iterators that change state without knowing why.

To answer your question: `seek()` should throw an exception and not change state. The `directoryIterator` (maybe some others too) should be changed to either not implementing `seekableIterator`, or by finding out how many entries there are prior to `seek()` (but that doesn't fix the 'rewind` when seeking backwards problem).

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Personally, I think throwing an exception should not be the norm, but your explanation on why directoryIterator is a bad use-case of seekableIterator is a solid counter-argument and indicates why it should be handled as a special exception rather than retooling the interface to not assume the thrown exception for the interface.

Comment: More specifically, I think throwing an exception for that specific interface should not be the norm, since it adds confusion regarding when to rely on the `valid` method versus when to assume an exception. Would it be more confusing/damaging to alter the iterator's state by throwing an exception *and* updating the position so that `valid` returns false?

Comment: No. I think it will be possible, however, I do not know if this would be considered a BC break, and would cause any issues in userland code  (although if it does, that code is probably too fragile to begin with).  Maybe it would be a nice fix for PHP7.

Comment: @Anthony This is actually designed behavior, as it's covered by a [test case](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/tests/dit_006.phpt#L33).  However, ["Implementations should throw an OutOfBoundsException if the position is not seekable"](http://php.net/manual/en/seekableiterator.seek.php) and I think there should be an exception [there](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L837).

Comment: @Anthony I've opened [Bug #70561](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70561), patched, and created a [PR](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1535).  Vote on it!

Comment: @Anthony This is [now fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1535)! In PHP 5.6.15 and later, `DirectoryIterator` will throw an exception like the other `SeekableIterator` implementations.